# Get contentintent of Notification at onNotificationPosted in NotificationListenerService?

Tags: android, notifications, listener, android-notifications

Is there any way I can retrieve the pendingintent of a notification once it's posted? I use a `NotificationListenerService` at `onNotificationPosted(statusbarNotification sbn)` to retrieve basic notification information such as the ticker text and the title of the notification, which is often posted by another app. Is there any way I can **retrieve the `contentintent`** set in the Notification by calling `setContentIntent`?

I'm new here so forgive me if I did something wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

Get the Notification of StatusBarNotification. Then access contentIntent property.

```
Notification n = sbn.getNotification();
PendingIntent intent = n.contentIntent;
```